# Providing divisibility condition given fraction identity

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math, divisibility, pythagorean-triples

If $x,y,z$ are positive integers satisfying 
$$\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}=\frac{1}{z^2}$$
prove that $20{\,\mid\,}xy$.

**My work:**

Expanding, we find 
$$(xz)^2+(yz)^2=(xy)^2$$
 I know the Pythagorean triple formula and I tried applying that, but I couldn't find a way to get $20$.

I've found a lot of questions on this website relating to similar questions, but none of them seem to refer to a divisibility condition.

If someone could help me find one, that'd also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you mean $(xz)^2 + (yz)^2$. Also, the Pythagorean triple formula mainly applies to primitive triples (it can generate nonprimitive triples as well, but not all of them), but we can see without too much work that all terms must be even here. (At least one must be even because no Pythagorean triple has three odd numbers, and therefore one of $x, y, z$ must be even, which makes at least two of the terms in this triple even, which means they must all be even.)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  What are square residues modulo $4$ and $5$?

Comment: Does this have any solutions?

Comment: @Matthew Daly: Yes, there are infinitely many solution triples $(x,y,z)$ with $\gcd(x,y,z)=1$. As an example, the triple $(x,y,z)=(15,20,12)$ works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $x,y,z$ are positive integers such that
$$\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}=\frac{1}{z^2}$$
Equivalently, $x,y,z$ are positive integers such that
$$\qquad\qquad\; x^2y^2=z^2(x^2+y^2)\qquad(\textbf{eq})$$
Aqua has already shown that $5{\,\mid\,}(xy)$.

To show that $4{\,\mid\,}(xy)$, we can argue as follows . . .

If $x,y$ are both even, then $4{\,|\,}(xy)$, and we're done.

If $x,y$ are both odd, then $x^2+y^2$ is even, hence the **RHS** of $(\textbf{eq})$ is even, contradiction, since the **LHS** is odd.

It remains to resolve the case where exactly one of $x,y$ is even.

Without loss of generality, assume $x$ is even and $y$ is odd.

Let $2^k$ be the largest power of $2$ which divides $x$.

Since $y^2$ and $x^2+y^2$ are both odd, it follows from $(\textbf{eq})$ that $2^k$ is also the highest power of $2$ which divides $z$.

Thus we can write $x=2^kx_1$ and $z=2^kz_1$, where $x_1,z_1$ are both odd.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&x^2y^2=z^2(x^2+y^2)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x_1^2y^2=z_1^2(x^2+y^2)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x_1^2y^2\equiv z_1^2(x^2+y^2)\;(\text{mod}\; 8)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(1)(1)\equiv (1)(x^2+1)\;(\text{mod}\; 8)\;\;\;\text{[since $x_1,z_1,y$ are odd]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x^2\equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\; 8)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&8{\,\mid\,}x^2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&16{\,\mid\,}x^2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&4{\,\mid\,}x\\[4pt]
\implies\;&4{\,\mid\,}(xy)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
as required.

This completes the proof.

Answer (score 2):

If $5\nmid xy$ then $x^2\equiv_5 \pm 1$ and $y^2\equiv_5 \pm 1$

- If $x^2\equiv_5  1$ and $y^2\equiv_5 1$ then $2z^2 \equiv 1$ so $z^2 \equiv 3$ which is not true.
- If $x^2\equiv_5  -1$ and $y^2\equiv_5 -1$ then $-2z^2 \equiv 1$ so $z^2 \equiv -3$ which is not true.
- If $x^2\equiv_5  1$ and $y^2\equiv_5 -1$ then $0 \equiv -1$ s which is not true.

So $5\mid xy$.

Now try $4\mid xy$. It should be easier.

Comment: Actually showing $4{\,|\,}(xy)$ is a little harder (but not hard).

Answer (score 0):

Some element of any triple is always divisible by $x\in\{3,4,5\}$ as shown [here](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/65802.html). If you follow the proof, it becomes clear. Sometimes one element is divisible my more than one of these. As a result, the product of some two of $A,B,C$ must be a $1$-or-more multiple of $20$.